# Redirect shell output to file and console both

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to redirect shell output to both console and file I have tried below

```
#!/bin/sh
exec &> >(tee -a log.log)
echo "testing"
```

And running the shell script in terminal like ./filename.sh but getting error "syntax error near unexpected token `>'", I'm using iTerm terminal in Macbook

Finally I want to run the whole script in AWS data pipeline.

Comment: Both `&>` and `>(..)` are bash specific constructs. Your shebang interpreter is set to run with `sh` shell which might not support those options

Comment: ...and if you _intend_ to write scripts to be run with `sh` instead of `bash`, use the `sh` StackOverflow tag instead of the `bash` one.